# Исключение при попытке наследовать метод geometry в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, исключения

Я пишу небольшую обертку для tkinter. Я изменяю методы `__setitem__`, `__getitem__`, `__init__`, `wm_geometry`. Эта обертка имеет цель упростить настройку окна и сделать ее более интуитивной. Одна из ниш для упрощения - `wm_geometry`, ведь формат ее единственного аргумента может показаться неочевидным.
Имеется следующий код, внимание попрошу заострить на методе wm_geometry:

```py
from tkinter import *
from typing import Any


def __str(i: str | None):
    if i == None:
        return ''
    return str(i)

def __unary_str(i: str | None):
    if i == None:
        return ''
    if i >= 0:
        return f'+{i}'
    return str(i)


class Tk(Tk):
    def __init__(
            self, screenName: str | None = None, baseName: str | None = None,
            className: str = "Tk", useTk: bool = True, sync: bool = False,
            use: str | None = None
            ) -> None:
        super().__init__(screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
        self._icon_path = 'default'

    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: Any) -> None:
        match key:
            case 'icon':
                self.iconbitmap(value)
                self._icon_path = value
            case 'title':
                self.title(value)
            case _:
                return super().__setitem__(key, value)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
        match key:
            case 'icon':
                return self._icon_path
            case 'title':
                return self.title()
            case _:
                return super().__getitem__(key)
    
    def wm_geometry(self, *args):
        """Sets geometry of the window. Arguments can be provided in different
        ways:
        wm_geometry(size: tuple, pos: tuple) -> None
        wm_geometry(width: int, height: int, x: int, y: int) -> None
        wm_geometry(geometry: str) -> None
        wm_geometry() -> str
        """
        if not args:
            return super().wm_geometry()
        if len(args) == 4:
            args = ((args[0], args[1]), (args[2], args[3]))
        if len(args) == 2:
            if args[0]:
                size = 'x'.join(map(__str, args[0]))
            else:
                size = ''
            if args[1]:
                pos = ''.join(map(__unary_str, args[1]))
            else:
                pos = ''
            args = [pos+size]
        super().wm_geometry(args[0])
    
    geometry = wm_geometry
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry((800, 600), ())
```

В результате его выполнения получаю исключение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PCyur\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\tkinter_wrapper.py", line 65, in <module>
    root.geometry((800, 600), ())
  File "c:\Users\PCyur\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\tkinter_wrapper.py", line 50, in wm_geometry
    size = 'x'.join(map(__str, args[0]))
                        ^^^^^
NameError: name '_Tk__str' is not defined
```

Такого имени в принципе в моем коде на существует, в чем проблема?

Comment: По поводу конкретно этой ошибки - просто поменяйте имя функции `__str`, чтобы оно не начиналось с двух подчеркиваний. В целом, переопределение `__setitem__` и `__getitem__` - это какой-то оверкилл, достаточно было два [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) сделать для icon и title.

Comment: Спасибо за совет о property

Comment: Но вопрос - как создать property для set- и getitem вместо set- и getattribute? Ведь это не просто геттер и сеттер, это поведение объекта как словаря

Comment: Объявляете проперти и сеттер с именем icon, и проперти и сеттер с именем title. И в них пишете то что у вас внутри кейсов. "Я посмотрел вопросы по этой теме, но все это выглядит не очень чисто" - наоборот, это использование getitem и setitem - это очень грязный хак.

Comment: Как-то так (title через super, потому что в наследнике мы переопределили title): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf94D.png

Comment: но это не даст возможность делать так: `self['icon'] = 'icon.ico'`, только так: `self.icon = 'icon.ico'`. Параметры чего бы то ни было в tkinter обычно переопределяются и получаются либо через `__getitem__` и `__setitem__`, либо через `config()` с аргументами или без. Я бы хотел сохранить единство стиля, чтобы заголовок можно было как поменять таким же синтаксисом, как цвет фона

Comment: "но это не даст возможность делать так: self['icon'] = 'icon.ico'" - это никак не упрощает работу. "Параметры чего бы то ни было в tkinter обычно переопределяются и получаются либо через `__getitem__` и `__setitem__`, " - вот это они очень зря сделали, считайте что это антипаттерн.

Comment: хорошо, вас понял, приму к сведению

Comment: Я бы сказал, наоборот, если бы все параметры были объявлены как атрибуты, то IDE давали бы подсказки, какие атрибуты вообще есть. А при использовании атрибутов - "ключей", фактические атрибуты можно узнать только через документацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переименуйте функции `__str` и `__unary_str` в `_str` и `_unary_str` соответственно.

Суть ошибки в том, что все имена вида `__<ИМЯ>` (но без двух подчеркиваний в конце), встречающиеся в теле класса, Python переделывает в `_<ИМЯ КЛАССА>__<ИМЯ>`.

Comment: Интересно, почему это так реализовано?

Comment: @ЮрычBRO, подробнее об этой особенности языка можно почитать в документации - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables